# how to adjust a heatmap color key and values everything

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a data as follows:

```
data<- structure(list(names = structure(c(5L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 
7L, 11L, 3L, 8L), .Label = c("Bin", "Dari", "Down", "How", "India", 
"Karachi", "Left", "middle", "Right", "Trash", "Up"), class = "factor"), 
    X1Huor = c(1.555555556, 5.2555556, 2.256544, 2.3654225, 1.2665545, 
    0, 1.889822365, 2.37232101, -1, -1.885618083, 1.128576187
    ), X2Hour = c(1.36558854, 2.254887, 2.3333333, 0.22255444, 
    2.256588, 5.66666, -0.377964473, 0.107211253, -1, 0, 0), 
    X3Hour = c(0, 1.222222222, 5.336666, 1.179323788, 0.832050294, 
    -0.397359707, 0.185695338, 1.393746295, -1, -2.121320344, 
    1.523019248), X4Hour = c(3.988620176, 3.544745039, -2.365555, 
    2.366666, 1.000000225, -0.662266179, -0.557086015, 0.862662186, 
    0, -1.305459824, 1.929157714), X5Hour = c(2.366666, 2.333365, 
    4.22222, 0.823333333, 0.980196059, -2.516611478, 2.267786838, 
    0.32163376, 0, -2.592724864, 0.816496581)), .Names = c("names", 
"X1Huor", "X2Hour", "X3Hour", "X4Hour", "X5Hour"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

I tried to plot it like below

```
rnames <- data[,1]                            # assign labels in column 1 to "rnames"
mat_data <- data.matrix(data[,2:ncol(data)])  # transform column 2-5 into a matrix
rownames(mat_data) <- rnames                  # assign row names
```

Then after I make it as matrix I use the heatmap

```
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "yellow","red" ))(n = 299)

col_breaks = c(seq(-2,0,length=100),  # for red
               seq(0.01,0.8,length=100),           # for yellow
               seq(0.81,2,length=100))             # for green

# creates a 5 x 5 inch image

heatmap.2(mat_data,
          cellnote = mat_data,  # same data set for cell labels
          main = "The heatmap title to be appeared ", # heat map title
          notecol="black",      # change font color of cell labels to black
          density.info="none",  # turns off density plot inside color legend
          trace="none",         # turns off trace lines inside the heat map
          margins =c(15,20),     # widens margins around plot
          col=myPalette,       # use on color palette defined earlier
          breaks=col_breaks,    # enable color transition at specified limits
          dendrogram="row",     # only draw a row dendrogram
          Colv="NA")            # turn off column clustering
```

But what I want is to

1- make the color key smaller

2- not to show any value or show with 2 values

3- I don't mind if one give a solution with ggplot

This is how it looks now 
[image]

and I want to have the xlabel straight without Xbefore them , is this possible?

Comment: Do you need the dendrogram?

Comment: @bouncyball  yes, I like to have that classification on the left